# Why does React state not change when called a second time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I'm currently building an interest calculator. Property values of `calcInfo` can be changed perfectly with sliders, but as soon as I add `calculateResult()` no values will be changed anymore and the default values are used.

Why does that happen and how do I fix that?

```
const CalculatorContext = React.createContext();
const CalculatorProvider = (props) => {

  const calculatorInformation = {
    initial_investment: 10000,
    monthly_contribution: 1000,
    length_of_time_years: 40,
    interest_rate_per_year: 7,
    financial_data: [],
    result: 2713059,
  }
  const [calcInfo, setCalcInfo] = useState(calculatorInformation);
  
  const changeCalculation = (value, property) => {
      console.log("-- hallo")
      setCalcInfo({...calcInfo, [property]: value})
      setCalcInfo({...calcInfo, financial_data: calculateResult()})
  }

  const calculateResult = () => {
    const initial_investment = calcInfo.initial_investment
    const contribution_per_month = calcInfo.monthly_contribution
    const contribution_per_year = contribution_per_month * 12
    const years = calcInfo.length_of_time_years
    const interest_rate = parseFloat(calcInfo.interest_rate_per_year)
    let result = initial_investment
  
    const years_interests = []
    const years_results = []

    for (let year = 0; year < years; year++) {
      result += contribution_per_year
      result = result / 100 * (100 + interest_rate)
  
      years_interests.push(year)
      years_results.push(result)
    }

    const financial_data = {
      labels: years_interests,
      datasets: [{
          label: 'Vermögensentwicklung über gewählten Zeitraum',
          data: years_results,
      }]
    }

    return financial_data
  }
    
  return (
    <CalculatorContext.Provider value={{calcInfo, changeCalculation}}>
      {props.children}
    </CalculatorContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

```
<input className="calculator-slider" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value={length_of_time_years}
        onChange={(e) => context.changeCalculation(parseInt(e.target.value), "length_of_time_years")}></input>
```

Comment: `useState`'s method of updating state is asynchronous by nature. There is no guarantee that the first `setCalcInfo` will finish running before the second one triggers. Thus, the second invocation will operate on stale data.

Comment: @Andrew actually, due to closures, isn't it guaranteed that the second `setCalcInfo` _will_ indeed run on the non-updated version of state? How could the second `setCalcInfo` possibly have reference to the new version of state?

Comment: @Nick The variable `calcInfo` is declared in the scope above the event handler, `changeCalculation`, so it would always be using the most updated version (even if that most updated version isn't what the user thinks it is). I don't think there would be a scope issue

Comment: I think it has to deterministically hold reference to the version of state as of that render unless you memoize the handler.

Comment: @Andrew using this example, I guarantee every time you click the button will just add 1 to the count, it's completely guaranteed that the adder function has closure over the previous version of state: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-bash-rl7cf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Nick Hah, I actually just did the same thing! I added an explicit `sleep` and it did not update twice. https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-fire-oqos4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Andrew great minds! Yeah the whole component is just a function, it's just javascript and subject to the same old closure rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As-is, your state-setting function has *closure* over the *current* version of state (as of that render). One way to make sure you're always using the most up-to-date version of state is to use a callback function:

```js
const changeCalculation = (value, property) => {
  setCalcInfo(c => ({...c, [property]: value}))
  setCalcInfo(c => ({...c, financial_data: calculateResult()}))
}
```

**Edit:** by the way, if you need the updated version of `calcInfo` *inside of* calculate result, I recommend passing `calcInfo` directly to `calcuateResult` or I guess running it as an effect.

Of course, possibly the *best* solution would be *not* storing `financial_data` in state at all since it's purely derived state and is therefore redundant to the rest of your state.

## On Derived State

**Edit 2:** Just to expand on what I mean by not storing `financial_data`. Since it's purely derived state, you can get this information from a function at any time rather than storing it redundantly.

You can therefore make this function standalone somewhere:

```js
const getFinancialData = (calcInfo) => {
  const initial_investment = calcInfo.initial_investment
  const contribution_per_month = calcInfo.monthly_contribution
  const contribution_per_year = contribution_per_month * 12
  const years = calcInfo.length_of_time_years
  const interest_rate = parseFloat(calcInfo.interest_rate_per_year)
  let result = initial_investment
  
  const years_interests = []
  const years_results = []

  for (let year = 0; year < years; year++) {
    result += contribution_per_year
    result = result / 100 * (100 + interest_rate)

    years_interests.push(year)
    years_results.push(result)
  }

  const financial_data = {
    labels: years_interests,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Vermögensentwicklung über gewählten Zeitraum',
        data: years_results,
    }]
  }

  return financial_data
}
```

Then, in any component where you need this info, simply call the function. At that point you'll always have the most up-to-date information and will not have to worry about data being out of sync:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const {calcInfo} = useContect(CalculatorContext);

  // Purely derived state
  const financialData = getFinancialData(calcInfo)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I still got an issue. I pass `calcInfo` directly to `calculateResult`, but it's not yet updated at this point. The calculation is always one render behind. When the slider is at 2, it calculates with 1. When the slider is at 3, it calculates with 2 and so on.

Comment: I solved it, but I don't think it's the best way haha I just added the following code before I add the financial data:
`const helper = calcInfo
    helper[property] = value
    const calculationData = calculateResult(helper)`

Comment: @Maurice I updated my answer to go into more detail about how to remove financial data from state altogether and use a function to always have the current state of it

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Just wonder if it's still the best way, if I need the data in two components (`financial_data` ist for chart, `result` is shown in another component)?

Comment: You could potentially create some selectors, which can be composed together to build state off of itself. Check out the package `reselect`!